# A Game of Chance,a simulator for a very simple dice game

Tags: c

Can anyone please tell what is wrong with my code?

player will roll two dice. In the first throw if the sum of the two
dice is equal to 7 or 11, player wins. If the sum is equal to 2, 3, or 12 
player loses. Any other sum, the game will continue, and the sum 
will become players “points”. The player will roll the two dice again
and again to achieve the players “points”. If the player achieves this,
the player wins. If the player rolls a 7 before achieving the “points”
the player loses.

peace!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int rand_num()
{
    return ( 1 + (rand()%6) );
}

int main( void )
{
    int D1, D2, score, point;
    int D3, D4, score_n = 0;

    srand ( time( NULL ) );

    D1 = rand_num();
    D2 = rand_num();

    score = D1 + D2;
    printf( "You rolled %d + %d = %d", D1, D2, score );

    if ( score == 7 || score == 11 )
        printf( "\n\nYou win!");

    else if ( score == 2 || score == 3 || score == 12 )
        printf( "\n\nYou lose!");

    else
        {
            point = score;
            printf( "\n\nYou must get %d to win", point);

            do
            {
                D3 = rand_num();
                D4 = rand_num();

                score_n = D3 + D4;

                printf( "\n\nYou rolled %d + %d = %d", D3, D4, score_n );   

                if ( score_n == 7 ) 
                    printf( "\n\nYou lose!" );


                if ( score_n == point )
                    printf( "\n\nYou win!" );

            }while ( score_n == point || score_n == 7 );            


        }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with it now? Compile time error? Run time error? Incorrect output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 }while ( score_n == point || score_n == 7 );
```

The loop only continues if score == point or 7, you want

```
 }while ( score_n != point && score_n != 7 );
```