# How to define a function in Swift without running it

Tags: swift

Starting from the Simple C program found [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27467067/a-game-of-chance-a-simulator-for-a-very-simple-dice-game), I've done it again in Swift and here's the code:

```
import Foundation

// variables and constants:

var dice1, dice2: UInt32
var score, scoreToWin, diceSum: Int
dice1 = 0
dice2 = 0
diceSum = 0

// functions:

func rollDice() ->Int {
  dice1 = arc4random() % 6 + 1
  dice2 = arc4random() % 6 + 1
  diceSum = Int(dice1 + dice2)
  println("\(diceSum)")
  return diceSum
}

// main:

score = rollDice()

println("\(dice1) \(dice2) \(score)")

switch score {
  case 7, 11:
    println("score=\(score)\nYou WIN")
  case 2, 3, 12:
    println("score=\(score)\nYou LOOSE")
  default:
    println("You have to roll a \(score) to WIN")
    do {
      scoreToWin = score
      diceSum = rollDice()
    if diceSum == 7 { println("You LOOSE") }
    else if diceSum == scoreToWin { println("You WIN") }
    } while (diceSum != scoreToWin && diceSum != 7)
}
```

This is a possible output:

- 6
- 3 3 6
- You have to roll a 6 to WIN
- 6
- You WIN
- Program ended with exit 0

I was not expecting the first line of output, because the first line indicate the function rollDice() was run while been defined.
How can I define a function without actually running it?

Comment: There's a `println` in the function so the line `score = rollDice()` that invokes the function will result in the first line in your example output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`score = rollDice()` would print the `6` you are seeing due to the `println("\(diceSum)")` you are doing in the `rollDice` method.

Declaring a method **does not run it**. Not in swift, nor in any other language I can think of.

Comment: definitely Yes. I tested it, the variable diceSum remain equal to 0 until rollDice() is called for the first time. Thank you.